# jemalloc.resident is increasing upto 70GB in CH-20.6.3.28 , Is it memory leak? Do we have any fixes for it?

Tags: clickhouse

`jemalloc.resident` is increasing upto 70GB in CH-20.6.3.28 , Is it memory leak? Do we have any fixes for it?

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/23790 <- contains some tips on how to debug and several prompts to upgrade to the latest 20.8 version

Comment: In any case their bugtracker is probably a better place for this.

Comment: Thanks @dratenik, That article does not help me . Let me give some more details for my issue. In my server I have 128Gib Ram and 32 Gib Swap, The Insert and select both queries run on this server. The RSS memories grows to peak (70 Gib) and then drop to very low in 10-12 hrs. At the same time the `jemalloc.resident` also grows to 70GiB, I have not seen peak memory going more than 300MiB. I doubt insert queries eating lot of memory.

Comment: I am using sharding and replication both running at 2+1 cluster. @ instances of clickhouse are running.

Comment: Also I can see lot of exceptions; ` <Trace> Connection (172.16.2.9:9000): Connecting. Database: DB_1. User: default` and  `<Warning> ConnectionPoolWithFailover: Connection failed at try №1, reason: Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused (172.16.2.9:9000) (version 20.6.3.28 (official build))` here 72.16.2.9 is not the IP of clickhouse containers but I hope this is warning and can be ignored. Not sure from where Clickhouse is picking IPs of another app running on same server. Searched every configuration files and no where this IP is present